# How can I use tie() to redirect STDOUT, STDERR only for certain packages?

Tags: perl, filehandle, tie

I need to work with some libraries that unfortunately log diagnostic
messages to STDOUT and STDERR. By using `tie`, I can redirect those
writes to a function that captures those. Since I don't want all
STDOUT and STDERR output of my programs to be captured thtough the
tied handle, I'd like to do this only for certain packages.

I have come up with a solution where the actual behavior is determined
by looking at caller() as can be seen below, but I have the feeling
that there has to be a better way... Is there a more elegant solution?

```
package My::Log::Capture;
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

sub TIEHANDLE {
    my ($class, $channel, $fh, $packages) = @_;
    bless {
        channel => lc $channel,
        fh => $fh,
        packages => $packages,
    }, $class;
}

sub PRINT {
    my $self = shift;
    my $caller = (caller)[0];
    if ($caller ~~ $self->{packages}) {
        local *STDOUT = *STDOUT;
        local *STDERR = *STDERR;
        given ($self->{channel}) {
            when ('stdout') {
                *STDOUT = $self->{fh};
            }
            when ('stderr') {
                *STDERR = $self->{fh};
            }
        }
        # Capturing/Logging code goes here...
    } else {
        $self->{fh}->print(@_);
    }
}

1;

package main;

use My::Foo;
# [...]
use My::Log::Capture;
open my $stderr, '>&', *STDERR;
tie *STDERR, 'My::Log::Capture', (stderr => $stderr, [qw< My::Foo >]);
# My::Foo's STDERR output will be captured, everyone else's STDERR
# output will just be relayed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from fixing the libraries, I can think of only one solution that might be better.

You can re-open `STDOUT` and `STDERR` file handles into your own file handles. Then, re-open `STDOUT` and `STDERR` with your tied handles.

For example, here's how you do it for `STDOUT`:

```
open my $fh, ">&", \*STDOUT or die "cannot reopen STDOUT: $!";
close STDOUT; 

open STDOUT, ">", "/tmp/test.txt"; 

say $fh "foo"; # goes to real STDOUT
say "bar";     # goes to /tmp/test.txt
```

You can read [perldoc -f open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) for all the gory details on what ">&" and such does.

Anyway, instead of "/tmp/test.txt" you can replace that open call with the setup for your tied file handle.

Your code will have to always use an explicit file handle to write or use [select](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) to switch file handles:

```
select $fh;
say "foo"; # goes to real STDOUT

select STDOUT;
say "bar"; # goes to /tmp/test.txt
```

Comment: Btw, if you only needed to worry about `STDOUT`, you might be able to do this with just `select`.